# What does the leading zero means?

Tags: javascript

I realized this while using the Chrome Devtools.

```
100 + 2 // outputs 102
0100 + 2 // outputs 66
01001 + 6 // outputs 519
060 + 3 // outputs 51
024 + 9 // outputs 29
```

Anyone can explain what is going on?

Comment: It's octal. Just remove the 0.

Comment: if you start the number with zero that means the number is octal, read here about octal system http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal

Answer (score 1):

The leading zero indicates that the number literal is in octal, that is, base 8.

Answer (score 0):

`0` starts an [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) literal, not a decimal.